# Special characters in attribute options

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

When I am trying to add a special character "&" in a custom product attribute option. The characters after it are cut off, & included. It does not work if you enter it as an HTML entity "&" either. Is there a way to add such characters as attribute options?

Comment: Can you please add your code here?

Comment: There is no code. This happens when you try to add an attribute option for a dropdown - type attribute trough the admin interface.

Comment: Try with this code : &#38 OR &amp;

Comment: It does not help as both start with "&". Both get cropped.